# How to install gemfile on osx?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install the following gem from the command line following the instructions:
https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography

Executing:
gem 'neography'

Results in "Unknown command neography".

I have "bundle" gem installed from executing "gem install bundle".

What step am I missing? Does this have to be done for each individual project? Or is this supposed to install to environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `gem install neography`.

To create a Gemfile for your application, you need to look into the [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) gem's Gemfile. Basically, just create a file named `Gemfile` in your project root with a source and your list of gems and run the command `bundle install`.

A Gemfile that would work for you in this case is:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'neography'
```